# Error converting from datetime UTC to datetimeoffset when kind is Utc

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

There is an error converting a DateTime in UTC to a DateTimeOffset type
when the kind is Utc.

The `origDateTime` comes from webservice so I don't have control of the content or format.

In most of the cases it comes with `Kind=Unspecified` (even tough the time is in Utc) and then it's working, but in rare cases the `Kind=Utc` and then the conversion to DateTimeOffset throws an exception:

> "The UTC Offset for Utc DateTime instances must be 0. Parameter name: offset"

How should I solve this?

```csharp
try {

    //causees error !!!!
    DateTime databaseUtcTime = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2016 6:25:20 PM");
    var localTimeTemp = databaseUtcTime.ToLocalTime();
    DateTime origDateTime = localTimeTemp.ToUniversalTime();

    //this is working
    //DateTime origDateTime = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2016 6:25:20 PM");
    
    string timeZoneName = "Pacific Standard Time";
    TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
    DateTimeOffset localTime = new DateTimeOffset(origDateTime, localTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(origDateTime));
    return localTime;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    string msg = ex.Message;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: DataTime Parse automatically converts to UTC time using timezone settings so there is no need to convert.  Connection to a database also use UTC time automatically so your code doesn't make a lot of sense.  Only use timezone offsets when inputting data collected in another timezone or when you want to display time in another timezone.  The Net library functions store time in the computer as a number in UTC and automatically converts the UTC when inputting or outputting.

Comment: i need to convert each datetime to a datetimeoffset using different timezones (according to another field) to be able to show in different timezones. Xavier answer solved the problem. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things:

- If you really need to switch the `Kind` of a `DateTime` without adjusting its value, use `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.  It is cleaner than dealing with ticks.  However, I don't think you really need to do this.
- Don't use `ToLocalTime` or `ToUniversalTime`.  Both of these will use the time zone setting of the *server* in the conversion process.
- I'm not sure that your *real* code is actually parsing a string, because you indicated that it is coming from the database.  If it's coming from the database, then no string parsing should be involved.  Just do the following:

  ```
  DateTime databaseUtcTime = (DateTime) yourDataReader["YourDataField"];
  ```
- Once you have the input, you can then convert using the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` functions.  Your existing code doesn't correctly convert the time, it just assigns an offset without correctly adjusting the time value.

  Since you wanted your output to be a `datetimeoffset`, then the easiest way is to first convert your input `datetime` to a `datetimeoffset` with zero for the offset (since it comes from UTC).

  ```
  DateTimeOffset dtoUtc = new DateTimeOffset(databaseUtcTime, TimeSpan.Zero);
  ```

  Then it's fairly simple to convert:

  ```
  string timeZoneName = "Pacific Standard Time";
  TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
  DateTimeOffset dtoLocal = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtoUtc, localTimeZone);
  ```

Comment: The use of string is just for testing purpose, same for ToUniversalTime.
It's just to simulate the data coming from the server.
Can you please explain what is the difference between what i did adding offset in constructor   DateTimeOffset localTime = new DateTimeOffset(origDateTime, localTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(origDateTime));
and your code which use ConvertTime ?

Comment: i saw the difference, your code really take the date and modify it to {4/2/2016 11:25:20 AM -07:00}
by definition I only need to do the offset, otherwise i would use your code. 
thank you.

Comment: The date and time in a `DateTimeOffset` are the *local* time, already adjusted for that offset.  This is not just a .NET thing - it's by ISO8601 convention.  The timestamp `2016-04-02T18:25:20+00:00` is equivalent to `2016-04-02T11:25:20-07:00`.  If you just apply an offset without adjusting the time value, you're actually referring to a completely different point in time.

Comment: it seems you were right, thanks a lot for your insight. it helped me a lot.

now that i use your code, how can i convert to local time without taking into consideration the daylight saving?
with the offset, in case i have only time without date - passed to me by date with min year, for example  {1/1/0001 2:00:00 PM}
i used the following:
 localTime = new DateTimeOffset(origDateTime, localTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
how can i do similar with your code?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you want it to consider DST?  That is the time actually followed in the region specified.  Converting time without a date to a different time zone is nonsense.  You have to pick *some* date to fix it to.

Answer (score 3):

So your problem will be solved if you consistently set your `DateTimeKind` to `Unspecified`, isn't it?

Try this:

```
DateTime origDateTime = new DateTime(origDateTimeUnspecifiedKind.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Integrated with your example:

```
        try
        {

            //cause error !!!!
            DateTime databaseUtcTime = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2016 6:25:20 PM");
            var localTimeTemp = databaseUtcTime.ToLocalTime();
            DateTime origDateTimeUnspecifiedKind = localTimeTemp.ToUniversalTime();

            // FIX: specify the kind
            DateTime origDateTime = new DateTime(origDateTimeUnspecifiedKind.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

            //this is working
            //DateTime origDateTime = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2016 6:25:20 PM");

            string timeZoneName = "Pacific Standard Time";
            TimeZoneInfo localTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
            DateTimeOffset localTime = new DateTimeOffset(origDateTime, localTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(origDateTime));
            return localTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
```